# The element type “xsd:schema” must be terminated by the matching end-tag “</xsd:schema>”

Tags: xml, netbeans, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/books"
    xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/books"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    
    <xsd:complexType name="Mcdonalds">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Apple pie" type="xsd:date"/>
            <xsd:element name="Mcflurry" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Fries" type="xsd:double"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    
      <xsd:complexType name="Five guys">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Large fries" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="small burger" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="hotdog" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element name="cost" type="xsd:double"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

I'm trying to bind my XSD file, but I've been receiving this error and I don't see any problems.

> ERROR:
>
> The element type:
>
> "[ERROR] The element type "xsd:schema" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</xsd:schema>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not running the validator on the same XSD that you've posted (or your XSD processor is badly broken).

**Your posted XSD should *not* result in the posted error regarding a missing end-tag for `xsd:schema`.**

Use proper NCNames for elements – no spaces, as @YitzhakKhabinsky has already mentioned (+1):

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/books"
            xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/books"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
  
  <xsd:complexType name="Mcdonalds">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="ApplePie" type="xsd:date"/>
      <xsd:element name="Mcflurry" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="Fries" type="xsd:double"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  
  <xsd:complexType name="FiveGuys">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="LargeFries" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="SmallBurger" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="hotdog" type="xsd:int"/>
      <xsd:element name="cost" type="xsd:double"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

The above XSD is syntactically correct.  Use it exactly for your next test.  Note, however, the following:

1. The semantics of associating the `cost` element with `FiveGuys` rather than with each menu item, perhaps as an attribute rather than an element, is dubious.
2. You currently have no root-level elements defined, only types.

Comment: I also noticed a missing root element in the XSD. Though the presented XSD could be used via `<xsd:import ...` clause. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 1):

I validated the XSD by using Saxon. Here is the output of it.

Please try to remove spaces in the element names.

```
Running custom validation engine Saxonica 9.7.0.15 Validator...

file:/e:/Temp/dummy.xsd:9 Fatal Error: Invalid QName {Apple pie}
file:/e:/Temp/dummy.xsd:15 Fatal Error: Invalid QName {Five guys}
file:/e:/Temp/dummy.xsd:17 Fatal Error: Invalid QName {Large fries}
file:/e:/Temp/dummy.xsd:18 Fatal Error: Invalid QName {small burger}
```

Comment: I removed the spaces and its still the same situation